# Benefit of Razor Client Template

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I came across to [Razor Client Template](https://github.com/jchadwick/RazorClientTemplates) recently. But I don't completely understand the use of it. I would like to validate with the community, what I have understand.

1. Client template is just like the partial view, but we can load it as javascript. and then call that javascript when needed.
2. It would save a server call, as the HTMl markup is at browser/Javascript now.

Please let me know, would it be a significant improvement in terms of performance. **HOW?**

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to create same html markup at both the server and the client side. At those times you will have two templates: a razor template at the server side and jquery template(or someother) at the client-side. Having two versions to produce same markup create problems in terms of maintenance and development.

The Razor Client Templates library helps you to have a single template which is written in Razor and that can be used at the client-side as well and hence easy to maintain.

The important thing is the library is quite young so you may face limitations when you try to use complex razor templates at the client side.